# How to add custom FIX message at runtime?

Tags: quickfix, quickfixn

Our FIX provider implements a custom message type to send us trade commissions.

At the moment we are using QuickFIX/n (.NET) as FIX engine implementation and looking to the documentation, it seems that it's necessary to rebuild the library every time we need to add a new message type or a new custom field/s. This force us to add the necessaries messages/fields manually to the FIX dictionary XML file, use a tool to generate new C# classes and rebuild the library. Finally we need to manually reference the custom DLLs into our projects.

This cause a lot of issue about maintaining our apps for example with a with CI/CD process.

Is there a way to add the custom messages definitions at runtime avoiding this cumbersome process? If not, is there a way to manage custom message manually on receive?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by "add the custom messages definitions at runtime" but what you can do is just work with raw FIX messages and access fields directly without creating specific messages for them (after all FIX messages are just a key value map).
It's not recommended but if your messages change so often that it causes other problems it might be the way to go about it.

Comment: Finally I added the message definition in `FIX42.xml` file because I have `UseDataDictionary=Y`. The problem is that then I need to manage the message as raw message in the code without type safe (https://new.quickfixn.org/n/documentation/#item-less-type-safe-2).
This is because to add a new type you need to rebuild all the library with the DDTool (https://github.com/connamara/quickfixn/tree/master/DDTool) and use your "own" version. I'm looking for a way to add a type at runtime with the reflection or something else.